# Django CRUD the data is not visible even though it is added in database

Tags: python, html, css, django, postgresql

I am new to django and postgresql,I am currently doing CRUD and I have been able to make the create and insert page,I am able to ad the details as it appearas in the database
[image]

but it isnt appearing in the read page
[image]

here's the code in views.py

```
def show_cat(request):
    showcategory = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
    #print(showall)
    serializer = CategoriesSerializer(showcategory,many=True)
    #print(serializer.data)
    return render(request,'polls/show_cat.html',{"data":serializer.data})

def insert_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        insertcategory = {}
        insertcategory['category_name']=request.POST.get('category_name')
        insertcategory['category_description']=request.POST.get('category_description')
        form = CategoriesSerializer(data=insertcategory)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("hkjk",form.data)
            messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
            return redirect('categories:show_cat')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('categories:show_cat')
    else:
        insertcategory = {}
        form = CategoriesSerializer(data=insertcategory)  
        if form.is_valid(): 
            print(form.errors)   
        return render(request,'polls/insert_cat.html')
```

```
urls.py
from django.urls import  path
from categories import views
from django.urls.conf import include  
from django.conf import settings  
from django.conf.urls.static import static  



urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.show_cat,name="show_cat"),
    path('insert_cat/',views.insert_cat,name="insert_cat"),
    path('edit_cat/',views.edit_cat,name="edit_cat"),
    path('del_cat/',views.del_cat,name="del_cat")
]
```

I have tried everything possible but  I am not able to display the data on the 'read'page,please help

Comment: Can you add the template where you attempt to render the data? Passing the data through a serializer is a bit odd, can you add that too?

Comment: Are you using Ajax to get the data from the backend?

Comment: using postgresql and django